# Multiple peaks curve fitting using lmfit library in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, curve-fitting, data-fitting, lmfit

I have a [datafile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rzqb2wd2a36icn9/sample-data.txt?dl=0) where the first column is x-value, second column is y-value and third column is y-error. I would like to fit the data. I am following the example from [here](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html#example-3-fitting-multiple-peaks-and-using-prefixes) and my code is-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from lmfit.models import ExponentialModel, GaussianModel


file='sample-data.txt'
dat = np.loadtxt(file)
x = dat[:, 0]
y = dat[:, 1]



exp_mod = ExponentialModel(prefix='exp_')
pars = exp_mod.guess(y, x=x)

gauss1 = GaussianModel(prefix='g1_')
pars.update(gauss1.make_params())

pars['g1_center'].set(value=105000, min=75000, max=125000)
pars['g1_sigma'].set(value=150000, min=30000)
pars['g1_amplitude'].set(value=2000000, min=100000)

gauss2 = GaussianModel(prefix='g2_')
pars.update(gauss2.make_params())

pars['g2_center'].set(value=155000, min=125000, max=175000)
pars['g2_sigma'].set(value=150000, min=30000)
pars['g2_amplitude'].set(value=2000000, min=100000)

mod = gauss1 + gauss2 + exp_mod

init = mod.eval(pars, x=x)
out = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)

print(out.fit_report(min_correl=0.5))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12.8, 4.8))
axes[0].plot(x, y, 'b')
axes[0].plot(x, init, 'k--', label='initial fit')
axes[0].plot(x, out.best_fit, 'r-', label='best fit')
axes[0].legend(loc='best')

comps = out.eval_components(x=x)
axes[1].plot(x, y, 'b')
axes[1].plot(x, comps['g1_'], 'g--', label='Gaussian component 1')
axes[1].plot(x, comps['g2_'], 'm--', label='Gaussian component 2')
axes[1].plot(x, comps['exp_'], 'k--', label='Exponential component')
axes[1].legend(loc='best')

plt.show()
```

This code is giving me following plot (the fit is not working)-
[image]

I am expecting something like this-

[image]

1. Can anyone help me fitting the data in the plot?
2. Also in the [example](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html#example-3-fitting-multiple-peaks-and-using-prefixes) *value, min, max* for *center, sigma, and amplitude* were defined manually. Is there any way to get/ calculate those values from the data file?

**Update**

I tried using [find_peaks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) suggested by @mikuszefski in the comment. But it is also picking up all the small peaks (noises) as the image shows.
[image]

Is there a way to choose the values only for the larger peaks?

Comment: Try to use pythons [find_peaks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) to get starting parameters.

Comment: @mikuszefski, Thanks for the suggestion. But find_peaks also picking up the values of the noises (see update). Is there a way to get the values for larger peaks only?

Comment: Try to use the `height` and or `threshold` kwarg. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You really have to ("must", "are required to", "definitely under all circumstances") provide *reasonable*, finite, and plausible initial values for all the parameters.

When you say

```
pars['g1_center'].set(value=105000, min=75000, max=125000)
pars['g1_sigma'].set(value=150000, min=30000)
pars['g1_amplitude'].set(value=2000000, min=100000)

gauss2 = GaussianModel(prefix='g2_')
pars.update(gauss2.make_params())

pars['g2_center'].set(value=155000, min=125000, max=175000)
pars['g2_sigma'].set(value=150000, min=30000)
pars['g2_amplitude'].set(value=2000000, min=100000)
```

You are (literally "literally") telling the program that Gaussian #1 should start with a center value of 105000, and cannot under any circumstance go beyond [75000, 125000].

The data you provided and the plot shows that the two peaks you are interested in occur at `x` values of around 1.4 and 1.5.

So, the value for the center is around 1 and you told it the value was around 10^5 and could not go below 75,000.  That is the best fit under those constraints. The program worked without error or problem, and you got exactly what you asked for.

Again, for non-linear least-squares problems and curve-fitting, initial values **always** matter.  There are no situations in which they do not matter.

That said, using a peak-finding algorithm as mikuszefski suggests is a fine choice.

Aside: Bounds should be used primarily to constrain the logic/physics.  It might be reasonable to say the amplitude should be positive, for example.  There is nothing intrinsic about Gaussians in general (or, probably, your data) that demands that a centroid value of 74999 is non-sensical.   So, do not start with such bounds.  Start without bounds and as simply as possible.  Add such complexity only when it is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now the thing is, I have to work with similar 50 more dataset, each of which may have different center/peak. And providing these values for each of them will take long time. Is there a way to make the code understand those values from the dataset?

Comment: When you say "will take a long time" do you mean "in comparison to getting obviously meaningless results"?  Because, well, no, it probably won't.   The guesses for the centroids don't need to be great, they just need to be "in range".  If you have two overlapping peaks obviously (well...) you might have to take some care to keep those separate. But, in the sense "can peak finding be automated?", the comments above already hinted at how to do this: check out `scipy.signal.find_peaks` and/or `scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt`.